# why is my function outputting incorrectly?

Tags: c, function, factorial

I created a factorial function and my output for integer b is incorrect when it is set at 5, any ideas as to why? b should be equal to the integer 120 and I am getting the number -95449088 after I compile and run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int factorial(int x) 
{
    int i;
    for(i=1; i < x; i++)
    x *= i;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int a=5, b;
    b = factorial(a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

Comment: Which role should `x` play in your function? Is it the input n, is it the result n! or is it doing double duty, which will mix things up?

Comment: You might want to [edit] your question and specify what your program outputs, and what the correct output is.

Comment: will do, sorry I am new to programming as well as stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are using the same `x` value in the condition check of `for-loop` which is a mess up. Instead you can store the variable `x` to a variable `temp` and use this `temp` variable for checking the condition.

Please see below the corrected code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int factorial(int x) 
{
    int i,temp=0;
    temp = x; //store the x to temp
    for(i=1; i < temp; i++){ 
        x *= i;
    }
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int a=5, b;
    b = factorial(a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
}
```

Comment: The code Vishnu posted worked great for me, and I did not include maths.h I will try it with that thanks!

Comment: @Jackson . If it helped you then please accept my answer also

Answer (score 1):

Other have explained that you should avoid mixing input and output variables. This is good advice, and as a beginner you should try to observe it.

But this is a special case, and here you can re-use the input value, provided you use a decreasing loop:

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int i;
    for (i = x-1; i >1; i--)
        x *= i;
    return x;
}
```

It works because it implicitly initializes the return value with `x` and then multiplies it by all numbers below it, which is a possible definition for the factorial.